# How can I perform an HTTP Request?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm new to the Craft and I just want to ask if how am I able to perform an HTTP request in Craft just like AJAX. Where should I perform it? What should be the flow?

Comment: Please don't put "Craft CMS" in the title of every question. The entire website is about Craft CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the placid plugin to achieve this in the past. 
Is this what you are looking for?

https://github.com/olivierbon/Placid/wiki/Making-requests

Comment: I want to have an HTTP Request in my own plug-in